# Boto3 requiring AWS region in docker but not in local env

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-dynamodb

I have a script setup for a lambda that uses Python and will eventually connect to a DynamoDB table. I setup everything locally (a virtual environment using pipenv) using the docker image AWS provides for DynamoDB and it all worked without a hitch. Then I tried to dockerize the Python. When I run my table creation script in my local virtual environment, it runs without a problem. When I run the same script from within my docker container, I get an error. I'm not sure what the difference is. Right now, I use this line to connect:

```
dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb', endpoint_url="http://dynamodb:8000")
```

`dynamodb` is the name of the service in docker, so this should work. When I replace `dynamodb:8000` with `localhost:8000`, it works fine in my local venv. When I run it in docker, I get

```
botocore.exceptions.NoRegionError: You must specify a region.
```

The big question is why it's looking for a region in docker, but not locally. Here's my docker-compose for good measure:

```
version: '3'
services:
    dynamodb:
        command: "-jar DynamoDBLocal.jar -sharedDb -optimizeDbBeforeStartup -dbPath ./data"
        image: "amazon/dynamodb-local:latest"
        container_name: dynamodb
        ports:
            - "8000:8000"
        volumes:
            - "./database_data:/home/dynamodblocal/data"
        working_dir: /home/dynamodblocal
    lambda:
        build: .
        container_name: user-rekognition-lambda
        volumes:
            - ./:/usr/src/app
```

Comment: Your local has an `~/.aws/config` file but the docker container does not.

Answer (score 3):

In one of the AWS blogs, [local AWS Glue](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/building-an-aws-glue-etl-pipeline-locally-without-an-aws-account/), they share the `~/.aws/` in **read-only** mode with the docker container using [volume](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#volume-shared-filesystems) option:

```
-v ~/.aws:/root/.aws:ro
```

This would be the easiest way for you to reuse your credentials from host workstation inside the docker.

Answer (score 0):

boto3 has a bug that even if you explicitly give it an `endpoint_url`, it still wants to know a `region_name`. Why? I don't know, and it doesn't seem to use this name for anything as far as I can tell.

In most people's setups, `$HOME/.aws/config` contains some default choice of region, so boto3 picks up the `region_name` from that configuration, and then just ignores it...

Since probably your docker image doesn't have that file, the trivial solution is just to add `region_name='us-east-1'` (for example) explicitly to your `boto3.resource()` call. Again, the specific region name you choose won't matter - boto3 will connect to the URL you give it, not to that region.

So the full command becomes:

```py
dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb',
    endpoint_url="http://dynamodb:8000",
    region_name="us-east-1")
```